# Backing up a CentOS/Fedora install, but it has 3 partitions

Tags: windows, fedora

I'm trying to use `Win32 Disk Imager` to create an image from an install of CentOS/Fedora, however in both cases there is 1 partition (that is clearly not the system partition) and 2 other unreadable ones (windows claims that there isn't any data there and that they are unformatted).

How can i create an image to saftely backup the contents of the default CentOS or Fedora install?

I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know CentOS/Fedora but it is very likely that these "unknown" partitions contain an **ext4** filesystem, the default filesystem on Linux. The first readable partition is the boot partition, containing essential system files like the kernel, firmware and drivers. It is formated with a **fat** filesystem which is also known by MS Windows. But this should not matter if you use a real disk imager that copies on low level all bits and bytes without knowing something about the file systems.

I'm not familiar with MS Windows but maybe you will find such an imager for this operating system. Anyway, you always can boot a Linux Live CD, maybe with Debian or Ubuntu and use the `dd` command. For example if your SD Card is seen as device `/dev/sdb`, then on the command line you can use:

```
ubuntu ~$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=4M | gzip > myimage.img.gz
```

This will create a compressed image from the SD Card. To restore it you use:

```
ubuntu ~$ sudo gzip -cd myimage.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=4M conv=fsync
```

Try both commands before archive your backups.